# Initial R Shiny data frame load based on a URL parameter

Tags: r, shiny

New to R and Shiny and working on my first little app.  The code below works as I want but now I need to extend it so that when it is loaded there is a parameter in the URL (something like http://127.0.0.1:6804/?Sta_ID=1ABIR000.76) which is used in that first query to set the wqmdata data frame.  I've figured out how to use the parseQueryString function to grab that parameter out of the URL in the server code block, but I can't figure out how to use it in that initial data load of the wqmdata data frame?  That data frame is used to populate a bunch of stuff in the UI which is based on the specific station (i.e. every station can have a different list of monitored water quality parameters).

A little background on what I'm trying to do.  Eventually that pl45_wqm_data.csv file will be replaced with a call to a SQL server database to get the data for the app.  That database has thousands of monitoring stations with millions of observations so I obviously just want to bring back the data that is needed in that initial call.  The idea is to have a URL which can be called from an ArcGIS Portal app so users can use the interactive map (with a bunch of other data) to find a monitoring station then click on the station to launch the R Shiny app to visualize the monitoring data for that station.

Any ideas to try?

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

#Get monitoring data
wqmdata <- arrange(subset(read.csv(file="~\\R\\ShinyApps\\WQMGraphURL\\pl45_wqm_data.csv"
           , fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM"),Sta_ID == "1ABIR000.76"),Parameter,Fdt_Date_Time)

# Define UI for application that allows user to select a Parameter then get a graph
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    tags$style(type='text/css', 
               ".selectize-input {font-size: 12px; line-height: 12px;} 
        .selectize-dropdown {font-size: 11px; line-height: 11px;}"),
    
    # Give the page a title
    titlePanel(paste("DEQ Water Quality Monitoring Station Data for ",unique(wqmdata$Sta_ID))),
    hr(),
    
    # Generate a row with a sidebar
    sidebarLayout(      
        
        # Define the sidebar with one input
        sidebarPanel(
            #dropdown to select parameter to be graphed
            selectInput("SelectedParameter", "Select Parameter for Graph:", 
                        choices=unique(wqmdata$Parameter)),
            hr(),
            # Button
            downloadButton("downloadData", "Download Station Data"),
            
            helpText("Download file contains all monitoring data including field data parameters")
        ),
        
        # Create a spot for the barplot
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("ParameterPlot")  
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw graph
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
       GraphRecords <- reactive({
        filter(wqmdata, Parameter == input$SelectedParameter)
    })
    
    GraphRecordsRows <- reactive({nrow(filter(wqmdata, Parameter == input$SelectedParameter))})
    
    # Fill in the spot we created for a plot
    output$ParameterPlot <- 
        renderPlot({
            # Render the graph
            graph.title <- "Parameter Data Graph"
            yaxis.label <- paste(unique(GraphRecords()$Parameter)," Value")
            
            if (GraphRecordsRows() == 1) 
            { ggplot(GraphRecords(), aes(Fdt_Date_Time, Parameter_Value, group = 1)) +
                    geom_point() +
                    labs(x = "Sample Date", y = yaxis.label, title = graph.title) +
                    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1)) +
                    geom_text(aes(label = Parameter_Value), angle = 70, hjust = 0, vjust = -0.5, size = 3) }
            else
            { ggplot(GraphRecords(), aes(Fdt_Date_Time, Parameter_Value, group = 1)) +
                    geom_point() +
                    geom_line()+
                    labs(x = "Sample Date", y = yaxis.label, title = graph.title) +
                    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1)) +
                    geom_text(aes(label = Parameter_Value), angle = 70, hjust = 0, vjust = -0.5, size = 3) }
        })
    
    
    # Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
            paste(unique(wqmdata$Sta_ID), "_StationData.csv", sep = "")
        },
        content = function(file) {
            write.csv(wqmdata, file, row.names = FALSE)
        }
    )
    
}
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

More or less figured it out.  I'm getting a 'Warning: Error in : Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x, y' error when the page first loads (I guess because the plotOutput runs before there is any data supplied) but I'll figure out how to get that fixed.  The whole idea of reactive data in R is very foreign to me but very cool.

Here is the updated code.  I still need to clean it up a bit but this works:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

# Define UI for application that allows user to select a Parameter then get a graph
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    tags$style(type='text/css', 
               ".selectize-input {font-size: 12px; line-height: 12px;} 
        .selectize-dropdown {font-size: 11px; line-height: 11px;}"),
    
    # Give the page a title
    titlePanel(textOutput("titleText")),
    hr(),

    # Generate a row with a sidebar
    sidebarLayout(
         
    #     # Define the sidebar with one input
        sidebarPanel(
            #dropdown to select parameter to be graphed
            selectInput("graphParameters","Select Parameter for Graph:","graphParameters"),
            hr(),
            # Button
            downloadButton("downloadData", "Download Station Data"),

            helpText("Download file contains all monitoring data including field data parameters")
        ),

    #     # Create a spot for the barplot
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("ParameterPlot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw graph
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    stationidParameter <- reactive({
        query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
        query[["stationid"]]
    })
    
    wqmdata <- reactive({arrange(subset(read.csv(file="~\\R\\ShinyApps\\WQMGraphURL2\\pl45_wqm_data.csv"
                     , fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM"),Sta_ID == stationidParameter()),Parameter,Fdt_Date_Time)})
    
    output$titleText <- renderText({paste("DEQ Water Quality Monitoring Station Data for ",unique(wqmdata()$Sta_ID))})    
    
    observe({updateSelectInput(session, "graphParameters", choices = unique(wqmdata()$Parameter))})
    
    GraphRecords <- reactive({filter(wqmdata(), Parameter == input$graphParameters)})

    GraphRecordsRows <- reactive({nrow(filter(wqmdata(), Parameter == input$graphParameters))})

    # Fill in the spot we created for a plot
    output$ParameterPlot <-
        renderPlot({
            # Render the graph
            graph.title <- "Parameter Data Graph"
            yaxis.label <- paste(unique(GraphRecords()$Parameter)," Value")

            if (GraphRecordsRows() == 1)
            { ggplot(GraphRecords(), aes(Fdt_Date_Time, Parameter_Value, group = 1)) +
                    geom_point() +
                    labs(x = "Sample Date", y = yaxis.label, title = graph.title) +
                    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1)) +
                    geom_text(aes(label = Parameter_Value), angle = 70, hjust = 0, vjust = -0.5, size = 3) }
            else
            { ggplot(GraphRecords(), aes(Fdt_Date_Time, Parameter_Value, group = 1)) +
                    geom_point() +
                    geom_line()+
                    labs(x = "Sample Date", y = yaxis.label, title = graph.title) +
                    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1)) +
                    geom_text(aes(label = Parameter_Value), angle = 70, hjust = 0, vjust = -0.5, size = 3) }
        })


    # Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
            paste(unique(wqmdata()$Sta_ID), "_StationData.csv", sep = "")
        },
        content = function(file) {
            write.csv(wqmdata(), file, row.names = FALSE)
        }
    )
    
}
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: If the error comes from missing data for the plot, try out `req(GraphRecords())` (or other dataframes you use) in your `renderPlot`